# I need an image viewer controllable from terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an image viewer that can be controlled from terminal.
`feh` seemed to be the best candidate, many link it to `mplayer`.

The problem is that once opened, there is no control from terminal, only from the X-window.

As the `feh` manpage states:

> **In an image window**, the following keys may be used ...

`fbi` is another candidate, but it is not suitable for me given that it seems to work only in a system without X-display.

I play videos remotely through ssh with `mplayer`, how can I do the same for pictures?

Comment: Why do you need an image viewer from terminal? How do you want an image be viewed without X?

Comment: @Anwar I'm using my Android phone as remote control for my Ubuntu pc: open TerminalEmulatorForAndroid and ssh into the Ubuntu machine. Now I have full control on watching films on the wide screen of my pc using `mplayer`, cannot say the same about viewing my pictures. `feh`, `gthumb`, `eog` are controllable only from the X-window, the only control I have from my phone is to kill the process (CTRL-c) and reopen it with the next image. Hope this makes things more clear.

Answer (score 2):

When I first asked this question I already knew about `xdotool` which can send keystrokes to X-windows and much more. Example:

```
xdotool key a
```

I obviously didn't want to be typing command lines for each photo I had to view.
I've finally created my own script translating keystrokes to `xdotool` commands.
I can now control unconditionally any X-window from terminal.

Comment: Congrats on resolving your question. Consider improving your answer by adding the specific commands you've used so that people who stumble upon your question within next 45 years can benefit from it ;)